# Importing a second time inside a class instance

Tags: python

I have a project with a file structure like this

```
main.py
input/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
```

Inside main I import Foo and create an instance of it with these lines:

**main.py**

```
from input.foo import Foo
foo = Foo()
```

Inside foo.py I need to use threading so I import it and create a thread in init.

**foo.py**

```
from threading import Thread

class Foo
    def __init__(self):
        newThread = Thread()
```

Later I decided it would be useful to have a thread in main.py so I also imported it there using `from threading import Thread`.  Everything worked as it should up to this point.  I thought it was redundant to import `Thread` twice during the execution so I removed the top line from foo.py and ran it again.  This time I got `NameError: global name 'Thread' is not defined` when the program reached the line `newThread = Thread()`.

Is there a way for me to do an import in main.py and *not* import it again in foo.py?  It feels wrong to import the same class twice in one program.

Comment: "It feels wrong to import the same class twice in one program." - why? It's completely normal. It's not going to cause double initialization problems, and Python itself does it multiple times before your code even runs.

Comment: Technically yes, you could hand `Thread` to the initialiser of `Foo`, but it really isn't wrong to import the module once per file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should place all the imports and dependencies at the top of all your modules, even if other modules have the same dependencies.  Imports in python only exist within the scope of that module.  Even though the import statement exists twice, python is smart enough to know that it's already been imported and won't have to actually re-import the module.